# Why am I getting a duplicate foreign key error?

Tags: python, mysql, sql, database, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to use Python and SQLAlcehmy to insert stuff into the database but it's giving me a duplicate foreign key error. I didn't have any problems when I was executing the SQL queries to create the tables earlier. 
[image: This is my Python code to create the tables]

[image]

Comment: Posting code/errors as images makes it much harder for people to help.  Please edit your question and post all items as plain text.

Answer (score 1):

You're getting the duplicate because you've written the code as a one to one relationship, when it is at least a one to many relationship.

Sql doesn't let you have more than one of any variable. It creates keys for each variable, and when you try to insert the same variable, but haven't set up any type of relationship between the table it gets really upset at you, and throws up the error you're getting.

The below code is a one-to-many relationship for your tables using flask to connect to the database.. if you aren't using flask yourself.. figure out the translation, or use it.

```
class ChildcareUnit(db.Model):

    Childcare_id=db.Column('ChildcareUnit_id',db.Integer,primary_key=True)
    fullname = db.Column(String(250), nullable = False)
    shortname = db.Column(String(250), nullable = False)

    _Menu = db.relationship('Menu')

    def __init__(self,fullname,shortname):
        self.fullname = fullname
        self.shortname = shortname

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<ChildcareUnit %r>' % self.id

class Menu(db.Model):

    menu_id = db.Column('menu_id', db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    menu_date = db.Column('Date', Date, nullable=True)

    idChildcareUnit=db.Column(db.Integer,db.Forgeinkey('ChilecareUnit.ChilecareUnit_id'))
    ChilecareUnits = db.relationship('ChildcareUnit')

    def __init__(self,menu_date):
        self.menu_date = menu_date

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Menu %r>' % self.id
```

A couple differences here to note. the Columns are now `db.Column()` not `Column()`. This is the Flask code at work. it makes a connection between your database and the column in that table, saying "hey, these two things are connected".

Also, look at the `db.Relationship()` variables I've added to both of the tables. This is what tells your ORM that the two tables have a 1-2-many relationship. They need to be in both of the tables, and the relationship column in one table needs to list the other for it to work, as you can see.

Lastly, look at `__repr__`. This is what you're ORM uses to generate the foreign Keys for your database. It is also really important to include. Your code will either be super super slow without it, or just not work all together.
there are two different options you have to generate foreign keys in sqlalchemy. `__repr__` and `__str__`

`__repr__` is designed to generate keys that are easier for the machine to read, which will help with performance, but might make reading and understanding them a little more difficult.
`__str__` is designed to be human friendly. It'll make your foreign keys easier to understand, but it will also make your code run just a little bit slower.
You can always use `__str__` while you're developing, and then switch `__repr__` when you're ready to have your final database.

Comment: Hi, we're not using Flask code. Is there a different way we can do this

Comment: There is. SqlAlchemy has an method that creates an engine for you to connect with, there's also pyodbc and I'm sure at least 2, or 3 others. You'll have to read through the documentation to figure out how to make the above code work if you don't want to use flask.
It shouldn't be hard to switch it over. Just google/youtube it.